# API endpoints returning 500 err after deploy on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, elasticsearch, heroku, redis

The API endpoint is working fine on my local machine but when I deploy my Rails project to Heroku, some endpoints are returning 500 Internal Server Error. My tech pack is below, because I could not find a way to watch Rails log messages on Heroku, I could not share anym detailed information. What can be helpful for me is general answers for 500 error, like what could cause this and maybe a way of inspecting Rails log messages on Heroku. Thanks.

MongoDB, ElasticSearch, Redis, Swagger

The error message on Heroku logs is `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms (MongoDB: 0.0ms)`

Additionally, on my local I get the following error but the endpoint is returning 200 OK. `HTTP parse error, malformed request ()`

Comment: If you have the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs) installed, running `heroku logs --dyno=web --app=my-app -t` will allow you to watch your logs.

Comment: Unfortunately, any uncaught error will result in Rails returning a 500 error, so there is no general answer that will help you. You will need to figure out how to get access to your app's logs to understand what is happening.

Comment: Your `malformed request` error on your local machine might be related to running your web server with HTTP but making an HTTPS request.

Comment: Thank you guys, I realized that the problem is BONSAI connection on elasticsearch gem is not supperted on versions > 7.13 but the problem is I had other problems with < 7.13 I am just thinking to understand the problem. All you help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the problem is BONSAI connection on ElasticSearch Gem is not supported on versions > 7.13